# GitHub - Update a pull request when subsequent pull requests have been issued

Tags: github

I forked a project on github. Fixed a problem, raised a pull request. Someone pointed out a problem elsewhere within the project. I raised another pull request to fix the second problem.

Both pull requests await merging, but have community support. Using github only, how can I edit the initial pull request to add something to the change without impacting the second pull request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the pull request, click on 'files changes' then click the 'edit' button.